# HTML Helper add custom attributes to checkboxFor

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor, cypress

So Im currently writing a cypress test and would like to add a data-cy to checkbox's

But get an error on when im adding a data-cy="CheckBox"

```
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Steps, new { @class="form-check-input flex-shrink-0", @type="checkbox",name="BinComplaintRadios",@data-cy="CheckBox" })
```

Comment: Have you tried using an underscore instead of a dash, i.e. data_cy - MVC should convert it to a dash in the HTML

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Steps, new { @class="form-check-input flex-shrink-0", @type="checkbox",name="BinComplaintRadios",@data_cy="CheckBox" })
```

Had to underscore data_cy instead of hyphenated